# DAX Power BI - Show latest record according to date filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables in Power BI model, [Date] and [Quota]

- 'Date'[YYYYMM] is used as a period filter on the report
- I want to show the latest quota according to the maximum date of the chosen period

How can I write it in DAX / Calculated Column?

```
Example:

If I select YYYYMM = "202005" in filter.
Below table should show:

|product|quota|
|A      |10   |
|B      |20   |
```

```
Quota Table:

|product|quota|effectiveDate|
|A      |10   |2020-01-01   |
|B      |20   |2020-01-01   |
|A      |25   |2021-01-01   |
```

```
Date Table:

|Date      |YYYYMM|
|2020-01-01|202001|
|2020-01-02|202001|
...
|2021-06-09|202106|
```

To get the latest quota, in SQL it would be:

```
SELECT TOP (1) q.Quota 
FROM [Quota] q 
LEFT JOIN [Date] d on d.[Date] >= q.effectiveDate 
ORDER BY q.effectiveDate desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure in DAX:

```
FlagToFilter = 
var __ChoicedDate = CALCULATE(MAX(DateTable[Date      ]), FILTER(ALL(DateTable), SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[YYYYMM]) = DateTable[YYYYMM] ))
var __MaxFor = CALCULATE(max(QuotaTable[effectiveDate]), FILTER(ALL(QuotaTable), QuotaTable[effectiveDate] <= __ChoicedDate && SELECTEDVALUE(QuotaTable[product])= QuotaTable[product] ))

return
CALCULATE( countrows(VALUES(QuotaTable[product])), FILTER(ALL(QuotaTable[effectiveDate]), SELECTEDVALUE(QuotaTable[effectiveDate]) = __MaxFor))
```

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate your answer msta42a, but looks like this measure won't work if effectiveDate is taken out from the table.  Actually I need this measure as base for other DAX calculation so effectiveDate will not be in the table in final situation.

Comment: I figured out we can change the return statement to:
CALCULATE(sum('quota'[quota]), filter(all(quota), 'quota'[effectiveDate] = _MaxFor), values('quota'[product]))

and we can simply get product and latest quota into the table.  Thanks for your base!